# "Represent" or "Representing"

Tags: word-choice, present-perfect, present-participles

Mr. X approaches each case with a commitment to effectively represent your interests.

OR

Mr. X approaches each case with a commitment to effectively representing your interests.

Comment: Thanks for the "vote" of confidence. I hadn't even edited my post before you gave it your thumbs up!  Don

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, either version is fine, though I'm sure there will be those who disagree with me. Truth be told, however, I prefer my first example.

Oh, and being the stickler that I am, I recommend not splitting the infinitive (viz., *to represent* or *to representing*), so you wind up with,

> Mr. X approaches each case with a commitment to represent your interests effectively.

Or,

> Mr. X approaches each case with a commitment to representing your interests effectively.

When changing the infinite to the gerundial form, there may be a shade of difference between the two examples. Perhaps the second example has a bit more "life" to it, more action, as it were. In a sales pitch, perhaps the second example might be more persuasive. The "customer" can virtually "see" Mr. X representing him/her/them.

Comment: I agree. Grammar aside, the plural "interests" doesn't ring. Either of the above with the singular sounds better here in the midwest. The singular seems to be effectively a plural here unless constructed with something like "... your particular interest". You never hear "It's not in your interests" in conversation. This is strictly an opinion from a man on the street.